# assigning a destination frame to a prediction in h2o.ai

Tags: variable-assignment, h2o, predict

I like h2o.ai for machine learning using R.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf

I like random forests, but I'm making a few thousand predictions in a loop.
It is spamming up my memory with things like this:

[image: a list of predictions frame names in h2o.ai]

I can't afford to keep them all in memory.  I'm making my very nice computer work very hard.  That means it doesn't have the capacity to hold all the balls in the air at once.

If I could assign a destination frame name to the prediction then each new one would overwrite the old ones.

How do I assign a destination frame name when I am performing "h2o.predict" on an object?

Things that I have tried that did not work:

```
h2o.predict(object = rf.hex, newdata = test.hex, predictions_frame = "predict.hex")
h2o.predict(object = rf.hex, newdata = test.hex, destination_frame = "predict.hex")
h2o.predict(object = rf.hex, newdata = test.hex, model_id = "predict.hex")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that I am aware of.

But as an alternative, inside your loop, you could call `h2o.rm()` on the return value from `h2o.predict()`. It is worth calling `h2o.gc()` as well. Something like:

```
for(data in alldata){
  # ... prepare newdata
  p = h2o.predict(model, newdata)
  # ... do something with p here
  h2o.rm(p)
  h2o.rm(newdata)  # If also not needed any more
  h2o.gc()
}
```

**Aside:** you said "I'm making a few thousand predictions in a loop". Assuming they were all against the same model, remember you can batch them up, and give all thousand predictions in a single `newdata` dataframe. One call to `h2o.predict()` with 1000 entries is much more efficient than making 1000 `h2o.predict()` calls, for one `newdata` entry at a time.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  I tried stacking, but these are million by hundred size arrays right now and they can overwhelm the 32-bit java.  I think Oracle is trying to kill the Java market because I have to sign a contract with them to download the java that h2o.ai needs to operate, in this case with much more RAM.